# How to erase files in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift

I'm trying to find a way to erase files on a disk using Objective-C (or Swift).

Does Apple provide a "built-in" solution to overwrite files at their current disk location? Or does Mac OS X always write files to their original location?

Searching the Web (and StackOverflow) just shows threads where someone wants to just "delete" a file. I could try to write junk into the files I want to erase but that won't help me if OS X would write the new content to a different location on the disk.

I tried to retrieve the location using the metadata a Spotlight search provides but these results do not contain the file location.

I'm a bit stuck with that and any clue will be appreciated.

**Edit**
I did have a look at the Apple documentation regarding file access. It says

> When you close a file after writing to it, the system writes zeroes to any portions of the file your code did not touch.

and

> Truncate files to match the length of the data you wrote. For scratch files you plan to delete, truncate the file to zero-length.

If I get this right it means that the file should be "erased" when I open it, truncate the length to zero and save it. Then the file system should overwrite the content with zeroes.

Source (section "Zero-Fill Delays Provide Security at a Cost" at the bottom): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH7-SW1

Comment: you want to remove a file in a unrecoverable way?

Comment: If you know the path-URL of the file. Use one of the FileManager methods to erase the file. [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @BryanChen Yes, I want them to be unrecoverable (if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open an existing file and overwrite the data use an NSFileHandle*

It will do everything you need.

```
+ (id)fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:(NSString *)path
```

Will open the file, and seek to the beginning. Unless you seek to the end, subsequent calls to

`[myHandle write: data]` will overwrite the contents of the file.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilehandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Sure, I can overwrite the content of the file or truncate it at offset 0. But does this assure that the new "content" will be written to exactly the same location where the original file resides?

Comment: That's more a question of what the Filesystem will do (HFS+ probably) It may also be impacted by the type of media you are writing to.  If this is an SSD then you might have very different results from a rotating rust HD in that the flash memory may still retain the data in a recoverable way due to write balancing algorithms at the chipset level.

Comment: I stumbled upon a short block within the Apple documentation (see my edit in my question). To take the disk type (SSD vs. HDD) into account I will leave the choice of using the "erasing mechanism" to the user.

Comment: I have tried the way you have mentioned and it seems to work. Opening a file, truncating its size to 0 and closing it results in a file of 0 bytes. But: Is there any way I could check whether it really contains just zero-bytes?

Comment: Almost certainly the bytes still exist on the physical medium if you simply truncate.  The filesystem will never see them again, but they could be recovered with special disk tools.

Comment: But if I do not misunderstand the article I've mentioned in my posting HFS+ should fill "bytes that are not touched by my code" with zeroes. This tells me that the filesystem should overwrite the file physically, doesn't it?